# Is the set of sequences $(x_n)$ in $\ell^1$ such that $|x_n|\leqslant\frac1n$ for every $n$, compact in $\ell^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness, lp-spaces

I was thinking about proving a set $S$ is compact in $l^{1}$ space.

$S = \{f \in l^{1} : |f(k)| \leq \frac{1}{k} \forall k \}$

where $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be functions such that $f_{n} : \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{+}$

I thought of applying that a set $A \subset l^{1}$ is compact if and only if $A$ is closed, bounded and $Sup_{x \in A} \sum_{j \geq n}|x_{j}| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Discussing  a bit let me think of taking $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$, but it would not belong to $l^{1}$ as the harmonic series would not converge. How to proceed with this question.

**EDIT -**

Also, how the result changes if we would consider $l^{\infty}$ instead of $l^{1}$ space. I think in this case we can take for a fixed integer $N$, $v_{k} = \frac{1}{k}$ for $1 \leq k \leq N$ and $v_{k} =0$ otherwise.

then here $||v||  = 1$ and since $N$ is arbitrary so its bounded always, so the set is compact if we change the space from $l^{1}$ to $l^{\infty}$. Is this correct?.

Comment: Consider every $f_N$ defined by $f_N(n)=\frac1n\mathbf 1_{n\leqslant N}$, and proceed as it seems you wanted to, then the proof is direct.

Comment: Nice!! the $1_{n \leq N}$ is the characteristic function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $S$ is not bounded in $\ell^1$: for a fixed integer $N$, let $v$ be the element of $S$ define as $v_k=1/k$ for $1\leqslant k\leqslant N$ and $v_k=0$ otherwise. Then 
$\left\lVert v\right\rVert_1=\sum_{k=1}^N1/k$ hence $\sup_{v\in S}\left\lVert v\right\rVert_1\geqslant \sum_{k=1}^N1/k$. As $N$ is arbitrary and the series $\sum_{k\geqslant 1}1/k$ is infinite, we derive that $S$ is not bounded.

If we consider instead $\ell^\infty$, that is, 
$$S = \left\{f \in l^{\infty} : |f(k)| \leq \frac{1}{k} \forall k \right\},
$$
then $S$ is closed (since the functional $f\mapsto f(k)$ is continuous for all $k$) and relatively compact: for a fixed $\varepsilon$, choose $K$ such that $1/K\lt\varepsilon$  and use relative compactness of $\left[-1,1\right]^k$.

Comment: nice solution! I was thinking how would the answer change if we consider $l^{\infty}$ instead of $l^{1}$ ? I htink it is still unbounded in $l^{\infty}$ too, so its not compact in both $l^{1}$ and $l^{\infty}$?

Comment: I think for the case of $l^{\infty}$, for a fixed integer $N$, we could take $v_{k} = k$ for $1 \leq k \leq N$ then $||v||_{\infty} = N$ but since $N$ is arbitrary so its unbounded.

Comment: @BAYMAX Is $k\le 1/k$?

Comment: Nope, I realised that, so please see my edit in the question

Comment: Usually, it is better to ask a separate question. For this time I addressed a sketch of prove in the edit.